# Convert one XML structure to another XML structure using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am working on a project which requires conversion of XML of one structure to another structure. I got stuck with an issue of traversing a node from inside another node.
As my project involves many elements and attributes, i have created a sample input and output XML files. They are given below.

**input.xml:**

```
<GENERIC_SYSTEM_PARAMETERS>
    <Companies>
        <Company ID="10" Name="Cmp_1"/>
        <Company ID="20" Name="Cmp_2"/>
        <Company ID="30" Name="Cmp_3"/>
    </Companies>
    <Persons>
        <Person id="1">
            <Company_ID>10</Company_ID>
            <Age>30</Age>
        </Person>
        <Person id="2">
            <Company_ID>10</Company_ID>
            <Age>40</Age>
        </Person>
        <Person id="3">
            <Company_ID>20</Company_ID>
            <Age>50</Age>
        </Person>
    </Persons>
</GENERIC_SYSTEM_PARAMETERS>
```

**output.xml:**

```
<Main>
    <Companies>
        <Company id="10" Name="Cmp_1">
            <Employees>
                <Employee id="1">
                    <Age>30</Age>                   
                </Employee>
                <Employee id="2">
                    <Age>40</Age>                   
                </Employee>
            </Employees>
        </Company>
        <Company id="20" Name="Cmp_2">
            <Employees>
                <Employee id="3">
                    <Age>50</Age>                   
                </Employee>
            </Employees>
        </Company>
    </Companies>
</Main>
```

Please give me some idea/sample xsl file to proceed further.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could probably benefit from using an `xsl:key` here, but if you are having trouble, you should post the code you have currently tried. Thank you!

Comment: The way to proceed further is to think about the transformation you want to make and then attempt to write it in XSLT.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="Company">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <Employees>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../../Persons/Person[Company_ID = current()/@ID]"/>
    </Employees>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and add a template to spawn `Employee` nodes from the `Person` nodes in the source as required.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a description.

The template matching *GENERIC_SYSTEM_PARAMETERS* acts almost like
the identity template, but changes the element name.

The template matching *Company* contains the main part of the logic.
To "block" companies with no employees it starts from checking
the number of its employees.

If the number is positive, it:

- copies the original opening tag,
- copies own attributes (*apply-templates*),
- opens *Employees* element,
- and within it prints respective employees, but with some changes (see below).

The template matching *Person* contains another important part
of the logic. It:

- changes the tag name,
- copies its own attributes,
- copies only its child *Age* element, so *Company_ID* is not copied.

The template matching *Persons* actually does nothing, blocking
"normal" processing of this element by the identity template.

And here the complete script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="GENERIC_SYSTEM_PARAMETERS">
    <Main><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></Main>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Company">
    <xsl:variable name="myEmploees" select="../../Persons/Person[Company_ID = current()/@ID]"/>
    <xsl:if test="count($myEmploees) &gt; 0">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <Employees>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../../Persons/Person[Company_ID = current()/@ID]"/>
        </Employees>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Persons"/>

  <xsl:template match="Person">
    <Employee>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Age"/>
    </Employee>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This logic is useful to me.